# matching multiple file extensions with fnmatch()

Tags: php

In the typical file matching code:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file !== "." && $file !== ".." && fnmatch($mask, $file)) {
        $dirList[] = $file;
    }
}
```

I was trying to use a multiple file extension pattern like this:

```
$mask = "*.{jpg,png,gif}";
```

but it doesn't work. No files match. This is rather strange since the same pattern works just fine in a terminal. It also works perfectly well with glob(), returning the files I want. I know there's nothing wrong with the rest of the code because using "*.jpg" as mask also works with fnmatch. Wasn't fnmatch supposed to support the same patterns that are available in a shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not supported.

AFAIK the `*.{ext,alt}` is an ksh and bash extension to shell globs. And `fnmatch()` is a system function, but functionality varies among Unix variants (BSD has it, Linux/glibc seemingly doesn't). There exists an `FNM_EXTMATCH` constant which I believe would allow `{alt}` to work. But PHP doesn't support it / pass it on.

But you could just use `glob()` with the `GLOB_BRACE` option, which supports said `.{jpeg,png,gif}` matching. And by this you'll save yourself an readdir().

Comment: *(svn)* [file.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/file.c?view=markup) - for those who want to see how it's implemented

Comment: Interesting. In theory, you could pass `0x20` through if your libc supported _EXTMATCH.

Comment: Thanks. I opted for using glob() instead, as you suggested, since that supports what I need. Maybe in some future version of PHP this will be supported via that FNM_EXTMATCH constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly bracket notation is what I'd expect to work on bash, but the fnmatch() call fails for me as well (as does the square bracket suggestion). If you look at the discussion about windows compatibility for this function (under its definition) at php.net you'll see that the curly bracket notation is not considered for the regex implementation of the function.

Comment: The curly bracket notation does work on bash and glob(), just not on fnmatch(). The square bracket is used to match only individual characters and not three letter character groups, and that's already shown on the examples section of fnmatch() on php.net. I'll take a look at that windows discussion, thanks.